# CSS Animations - Stopping on hover, and returning to beginning the same way it animated in

Tags: html, css, animation

I'm working on a website with animations that play when you hover over certain elements, and I'm having trouble getting the animation to return to it's original state in a way that it doesn't just "hard-cut" after hovering off of the element. **What I'm asking for is, is there a way to make the animation play backwards after hovering off of it?** I'm using animation-fill-mode: forwards; to make the animation stay in place while the user is hovering over the element. Any answer would be helpful, whether it's a solution using css or javascript.

Comment: do you have fiddle link to your code? Would be realy helpfull to see, how your code works

Answer (score 2):

In most cases you could do something like

```
element {
//animate the original state
}

element:hover {
//animate to another state
}
```

As long as animations defined in your `element` block are `visually opposite` i.e. if rotating clockwise on `hover`, these should be anti-clockwise; it should give you the desired effect.

For your use case, please post a fiddle.